# using xcopy or copy to back up files?

Tags: windows, batch, xcopy

I have a local drive that contains a directory per user:

c:\user1\
c:\user2\
c:\user3\

and I have a remote drive (via a share) that contains the same directory tree:

f:\user1\
f:\user2\
f:\user3\

inside each directory can be any number of files but they are all .txt. i've been trying to create a batch file that can iterate on the local directories and copy files newer than X timestamp into the corresponding directory on f:.

is there any way to achieve this using xcopy or copy plus some batch magic?

thanks!

EDIT: to avoid confusion: I need to parse the users directories (can have ANY name), grab the files newer than those copied the last time and copy them to the directory with the same name on F:\

copy *.* is not what i am trying to do. more like:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b c:\users\*') do call dobackup.bat "%%a"
```

or similar

Comment: Try [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy). [ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145\(WS.10\).aspx)

Comment: `XCOPY C:\USER1\*.* F:\USER1\ /E /D` Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @Evan, thanks but I need to iterate through ALL the directories (i don't know the names) and copy the files inside newer than x date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robocopy is your friend in this. It has a flag that'll do exactly what you want.

```
robocopy c:\ f:\ /mir /r:1 /sec
```

That'll do a mirror copy, retrying open files once before moving on, and will also copy security. The mirror copy will also remove files from F:\ that no longer exist on C:\, which is something xcopy can't do. Also, after the first sync it'll only copy newer files.

If robocopy isn't a possibility for some reason, you can get kind of close with xcopy.

```
xcopy C:\*.* F:\*.* /S/E/H/D
```

That'll copy the entire C:\ structure to F:\, copy hidden files, and only copy newer ones. It won't remove files from F:\ that exist in C:\ though.

Edit:

Perhaps this'll do what you want:

```
 for /D %D in (C:\User*\) do xcopy  C:\User%D\*.* F:\User%D /s /e /d 08-01-2010
```

That'll iterate over all directories with User in them, and copy files newer than the first of August.

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to do something a little more complex than just do a copy c:\*.* f:, i mean I was trying to see whether you can grab the 1st directory, parse the name and copy the newer files to the same directory on f:\. I don't want to copy any other directory but those of the users. maybe i didn't explain myself well

Comment: something like: for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b c:\users\*') do call robocopy "%%a" "f:\%%a" /mir /r:1 /sec

Comment: @Mr Aleph, perhaps my edit will do what you're looking for.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 thanks, but it's not working. what i have to so is: xcopy c:\users\[directoryname]\*.txt f:\[directoryname] (where directoryname is the same on both drives)

Comment: this will list all the directories, how do I grab each directory and copy *.txt from them?: for /D %%a IN (c:\users\*) do call dir %%a\*.txt

Comment: OK, if I put the batch file in C:\users\ then for /D %%a IN (*) do call robocopy %%a\ f:\%%a\ *.txt /mir /r:1 /sec   --- works

Answer (score 1):

OK, if I put the batch file in C:\users\ then

```
for /D %%a IN (*) do call robocopy %%a\ f:\%%a\ *.txt /mir /r:1 /sec
```

works